# problem with synchrozation with database javascript

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, mariadb

I got a problem with synchrozation of code. So the function that checks if email is unique is returning value faster than loop in the query to the DB is done. Actually the code from Db is ending last:

```
async function isEmalUsed(email)
{
var isUsed = true;
isUsed = await conn.query("SELECT Email FROM Users", (err, rows, meta) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    
   
        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
       
            if (rows[i].Email == email) {
                console.log(rows[i].Email)
                
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    
     
 });


return isUsed;
}
```

**The post method:**

```
server.post('/register', async (req, res) => {

 if (session.UserID != null)
{
     res.redirect('/');
    }

let usedEmail = false;
const username = req.body.login;
var haslo = req.body.password;
const email = req.body.email;
var gender = req.body.gender;
var date = req.body.date;
var emailUsage=false;
let flag = false;

flag = await isEmalUsed(email);
console.log(flag);
if (!flag) {
    haslo = await hashPassword(haslo);
    conn.query("INSERT INTO Users (UserName,Password,Email, BirthdayDate, Gender) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [username, haslo, email, date, gender], (err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else { req.flash('success', "you've been registered!") };
    })
    res.redirect('/');
}
else {

    req.flash('error', 'this email is taken');
    res.redirect('/');
}


   
});
```

Comment: I would start by changing the query to "select email from users where email=<email>" this will help you eliminate the loop because it is most probably taking long to execute.                      So to check if email  exists you will then use if(rows.lenght > 0) then isUsed = true

Comment: why do you retrieve all records from db then loop through them, why don't just retrieve record where user.email == 'email' and check if retrieved object is null or not